# not working this mysqli_fetch_field_direct function in mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

When I used below `mysql_fetch_filed_direct` function in php 7, it's not working?

How to do the same with php 7?

```php
public function __construct($tableName) { 
    global $link; 
    $this->tableName=$tableName; 
    $res=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM ".$this->tableName); 
    $columns_total = mysqli_num_fields($res); 
    for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
        $this->columnsArray[mysqli_fetch_field_direct($res,$i)]="";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your text says `mysql_` but the code says `mysqli_`. Which are you really using?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_field_direct()` returns an associative array. Why are you trying to use that as the index of another array?

Comment: so what can i use instead of this function..?

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_fetch_field_direct()` returns an associative array. If you want to use the column name as the key in `$this->columnsArray`, you need to access the `['name']` element.

```
public function __construct($tableName) { 
    global $link; 
    $this->tableName=$tableName; 
    $res=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM ".$this->tableName); 
    $columns_total = mysqli_num_fields($res); 
    for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
        $this->columnsArray[mysqli_fetch_field_direct($res,$i)['name']]="";
    }
}
```

Comment: $this->columnsArray[mysqli_fetch_field_direct($res,$i)['name']]="";
this line not worked, 500 error occured

Comment: When you get a 500 error, check the PHP log for the specific error message.